# Django: do I need to make a caching method?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-models

I have a model `Person` where I do a lot of queries of the same type. For example, I may ask a lot of times the "profile picture" in the same page.

As you can see in my code, I've implemented a "sort" of cache: put the result in an array, and later, if there's a key in this array, return the result.

```
class Personne(BaseModel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Mise en place de cache :
        self.cache = {}
        super(Personne, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def url_profile_picture(self):
        # gestion du cache :
        retour = self.cache.get('profile_picture')
        if retour:
            return retour
        a = PersonnePhoto.objects.filter(personne=self,
                                         photo_type=PersonnePhoto.PHOTO_PROFIL)
        if len(a):
            a = reverse('url_public', kwargs={'path': a[0].photo})
        else:
            a = staticfiles.static('img/no-picture-yet.png')
        self.cache['photo_profil'] = a
        return a
```

I was wondering (because I'm a Django newbie) if it's useful of if Django has already a caching system on its own. What I mean is: will my query `PersonnePhoto.objects.filter(...)` access the database all the time -> I definitely need my own cache, or will it be cached by Django -> useless to write my own caching method?

Comment: I don't see how an arbitrary query such as this can be cached by Django, or any software component really. There is no way to tell if the `Personne`'s URL has been changed since the last read, short of querying the database. In fact, unless this property is read-only, you should consider whether your current attempt to cache would fail to invalidate in that scenario.

Comment: another thing to consider, assuming this model is related to "personne" and stored FileField, you can simply use the ORM to get the url and it should cache the result for multiple use on a single page. but that will depend on how you are really using this property (which we can't see from the code posted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [the `cached_property` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property). It behaves exactly the same like the solution you rolled out for yourself (with the distinction that `url_profile_picture` is now a property):

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class Personne(BaseModel):
    @cached_property 
    def url_profile_picture(self):
        a = PersonnePhoto.objects.filter(personne=self,
                                         photo_type=PersonnePhoto.PHOTO_PROFIL)
        if len(a):
            a = reverse('url_public', kwargs={'path': a[0].photo})
        else:
            a = staticfiles.static('img/no-picture-yet.png')
        return a
```

Comment: i think this cache would live for a very short time and not offer any real benefits (only lives as long as the object does, which for a single page load would be fine, and likely not require it anyway).  I'll add a sudo code solution I have used

Comment: @warath-coder I don't agree with you at all on this one. The solution shown by the OP has the same property (only lives as long as the object does) and he is not asking to change that but only if Django has that already covered - and indeed it does, provided one uses the `@cached_property` decorator. He also explicitly stated that "I may ask a lot of times the "profile picture" *in the same page*", which is exactly the use case that  `@cached_property` was created for and it offers a real benefit in such cases.

Comment: sure... and when you have 1,000+ page loads, you will have 1,000+ calls to the database. so, as I stated, for a single page load you are correct, this would work well, but on a high volume site, it won't.

Comment: Oh, come one. I use different kind of caches, as they are needed. That's pretty obvious, isn't it? I'm sure you are not suggesting that you need to use an external cache for *everything*. I see no indication in the question that the OP is looking (or particularly needing) and external cache.

Comment: `@cached_property` is a part of Django, because it is extremely useful when one needs to call the same method multiple times during a single request. OP indicated that that's exactly what he is doing and he rolled out his own solution that behaves exactly the same as `@cached_property`. OP asked if this kind of caching is built in into Django. The answer is yes, there is, it is called `@cached_property`, but you need to enable it. That's the *direct* answer to the and that's exactly what I said. It's an EOT for me.

Comment: I saw your point @Ludwik-Trammer, and you are correct; yet so am I... so not sure why the rant.  rather you should point out that my solution, although will solve excessive DB calls, would still have to make repeated calls to the cach (in my suggested the memcached service), where I imagine yours is storing it in memory for a brief time.

Comment: @Ludwik Trammer You're right, you've answered *precisely* to my question. Nevertheless, warath-coder 's suggestion will be useful if the site ever grows much more than expected. But for now, I need clarity = very few code. The lesser the better. I 'upped' you both, and thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```

In your model, i suggest something like this:

```
def url_profile_picture(self):
    # gestion du cache :
    retour = cache.get('profile_picture_%s' % self.pk)
    if retour:
        return retour

    else:
        a = PersonnePhoto.objects.filter(personne=self,
                                      photo_type=PersonnePhoto.PHOTO_PROFIL)
        if len(a):
            a = reverse('url_public', kwargs={'path': a[0].photo})
        else:
            a = staticfiles.static('img/no-picture-yet.png')

        cache.set('profile_picture_%s' % self.pk, a)

        return a
```

can read up more on django cache here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/

edit: then in your profile area, you can clear the cache on upload of an image to get it to display faster.

Comment: note: my solution will make lots of calls to the cache system if you use the property alot, so for such a small value, Ludwi's answer is likely better.